# Including a count data covariate into a 3 way factorial robust ANOVA and outliers in R

Tags: r, anova, biostatistics, count-data

I have a three way ANOVA testing the effect of phosphorus (5 rates) x water-logging x cultivar (one water-logging tolerant, one not) on shoot biomass. There are four reps. I'm using R to do the analysis and I'm using excel to read in my data to R.

Half way through the experiment we had to spray the plants with an insecticide due to insect attack. This happened at around the same time as we started the water-logging treatment. After the insecticide spay, plants started showing signs of damage due to the spray (not typical water-logging damage but a burning of the leaves). The damage became progressively worse and was mostly evident in the plants that were waterlogged and in cultivars intolerant to water-logging. Clearly the cultivars less tolerant to water-logging were weakened by the treatment effect of water-logging and were more susceptible to being damaged by the spray. Towards the end of the experiment, I used a score of either 0,1,2,3,4 to measure the damage done by the spray, 0 being no damage 4 being more than 75 % damage. The insect spray had a marked effect on biomass which was evident when graphing the data in R, in addition to the fact a few plants died due to the spray.

How do I include the count data of the spray damage into my analysis? Firstly, the spray damage is correlated with the water-logging treatment and with cultivar (cultivars that were waterlogged and intolerant to water-logging had the most damage, which is the same effect as you you expect to see in the treatment effects on biomass without the spray damage). So does this violate our ANCOVA assumption of non-correlated variables? Secondly, the spray score is count data, so how does this affect my model?

Also, how do we deal with outliers in R? Im also measuring the same effects above but instead of biomass I measured isoflavones (F) in leaves. The errors were not normally distributed and variances were unequal. How do I use a robust ANOVA with a covariate with count data?, What to do about outliers and skewed residuals?

```r
structure(list(pot = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 69L, 
70L, 71L, 72L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 57L, 58L, 
59L, 60L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L), rep = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), cultivar = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Dinninup", 
"Riverina", "Seaton Park", "Yarloop"), class = "factor"), Waterlogging = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Non-waterlogged", 
"Waterlogged"), class = "factor"), P = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 
36L, 36L, 36L), F = c(1.65, 0.61, 0.47, 0.57, 0.49, 0.71, 0.44, 
0.6, 0.52, 0.61, 0.48, 0.8, 0.79, 0.64, 0.44, 0.48, 0.69, 0.63, 
0.39, 0.68, 0.89, 0.66, 0.39, 0.52, 0.66, 0.51, 0.4, 0.55, 0.66, 
0.59, 0.54, 0.59, 0.45, 0.41, 0.47, 0.54, 0.5, 0.72, 0.39, 0.44, 
1.7, 1.78, 1.6, 2.34, 2.03, 1.97, 1.92, 1.88, 1.52, 1.88, 1.67, 
1.7, 1.97, 1.97, 1.88, 2.01, 1.88, 1.59, 1.97, 1.6, 2.08, 2.06, 
2.01, 2.22, 1.97, 2.13, 1.52, 2.5, 1.97, 1.74, 2.08, 1.3, 1.88, 
1.61, 1.61, 1.65, 2.05, 1.75, 1.61, 1.2), shoot.biomass = c(0.37, 
0.43, 0.52, 0.33, 1.24, 1.12, 1.28, 1.28, 0.48, 0.95, 1.35, 0.95, 
1.37, 1.4, 1.39, 1.34, 0.67, 0.8, 1.13, 0.32, 1.34, 1.53, 1.25, 
1.4, 0.58, 0.98, 1.46, 0.69, 1.44, 1.83, 1.65, 1.71, 1, 1.17, 
1.45, 0.98, 1.52, 1.75, 1.63, 1.7, 0.25, 0.24, 0.91, 1.17, 1.23, 
1.22, 1.26, 0.89, 1.54, 1.01, 1.48, 0.93, 1.2, 1.55, 1.4, 1.19, 
0.9, 1.29, 1.43, 1.31, 1.75, 1.92, 1.63, 1.64, 1.31, 1.43, 1.77, 
1.28, 1.34, 1.54, 1.66, 1.88, 1.29, 1.05, 1.63, 1.36, 1.9, 2.18, 
2.03, 1.68), spray.dmg = c(3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
2L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 
4L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 80L), class = "data.frame")

[![Figure 1. The concentration of formononetin as a percentage of dry matter (DM) before waterlogging treatment commenced (estimated means, LSD at p = 0.05). There was no effect from the P treatments.][1]][1]
```

[image: Figure 2. Three-way interaction among cultivar, waterlogging and P treatment for shoot dry weight (estimated means, LSD at p = 0.05)]

[image: Figure 5. The interaction of cultivar and the waterlogging treatment (a) and the P treatment and the waterlogging treatment (b) for pesticide damage on the top of the canopy measured at harvest. 0 = no damage, 1 = less than 25 %. 2 = 25-50%, 3 = 50-75%, 4 = >75%. I used a Poisson GLM since it's count data so not sure about LSD]

[image: Figure 1. The concentration of formononetin as a percentage of dry matter (DM) before waterlogging treatment commenced (estimated means, LSD at p = 0.05). There was no effect from the P treatments.]

Comment: I have also run the model md <- lm(F~cultivar*P+rep,data=iso) (This model is testing F before insect spray) but this has unequal variance, failing the bptest(md), library(AER), and residuals are not normal. There are some obvious outliers so I dont know how to remove these and run a robust ANOVA. Also not sure about which data transformation to use to "fix" the residuals and how this affects the ANOVA.

Comment: library(ggplot2)
library(Rmisc)
iso$P <- as.factor(iso$P)
tg5 <- summarySE(iso, measurevar="shoot", groupvars=c("P","cultivar","Waterlogging"))
iso$cultivar= factor(iso$cultivar, levels=c("Seaton Park","Dinninup","Yarloop","Riverina"))
ggplot(tg5, aes( x = as.factor(P), y = shoot, fill = Waterlogging))+
  theme_bw()+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6, position = "dodge",colour="black")+
  geom_errorbar((aes(ymin = shoot-se, ymax = shoot+se)), size = 0.3, 
                width = 0.4,
                position = position_dodge(.6))+

Comment: xlab("Soil P (mg/kg)")+
  ylab("Shoot dry weight (g)")+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0),limits=c(0, 2.5),breaks=0:11*0.5)+
  theme(legend.position = c(.11, .9))+
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title=NULL))+
  theme(legend.key.size = unit(4, "mm"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00BA38","#00BFC4"))+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 1, y = 1.7, xend = 1, yend = 1.943362),size=1,data = subset(iso, cultivar == "Seaton Park")) +
  facet_grid(.~cultivar)

Comment: This is my initial model. md1 <- lm(shoot~cultivar * P * Waterlogging*spray.dmg+rep,data=iso) It failed the shapiro.test(md1$resid) for normality. However, a bigger concern I have is the spray.dmg factor, i.e. the covariate, as this is count data. So unsure about how to run the ANCOVA

Comment: 1) Don't use the Shapiro-Wilks test or any other test to test for normality in this context.  Because the *p* value for these tests is dependent on the sample size, they're not particularly useful in this context.  Instead use q-q plots of the residuals or a histogram on the residuals.  Your eye and honesty are a better judge.  ... The residuals for the `shoot.biomass` model look both reasonably normal and homoscedastic.  The residuals for `F` look reasonably homoscedastic.  They're not terribly non-normal.  Their distribution probably wouldn't bother me *too* much....

Comment: 2) Advice:  a) If the distribution of the residuals is bothering you, use a *generalized linear model* with a [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) instead of the OLS model you have.  This is often a reasonable model in your field, so it's worth thinking about.  It allows for skewed conditional distributions.  In R, it's easy using `glm(..., family="Gamma")` and use `car::Anova` and `emmeans::emmeans` to examine the output.  b) You have like 16 terms in your model.  I would probably consider paring this down a bit, maybe just by dropping the 3-way interactions

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. From looking at the plots, I would expect there to be a three way interaction with cultivar, waterlogging and spray damage on shoot dry weight. So I run the model md1 <- lm(shoot ~ cultivar * as.factor(P) * Waterlogging*spray.dmg+as.factor(rep),data=iso). The 3 way interaction gave a p value of 0.053.......

Comment: I tested for equal variance using the Breusch-Pagan test, library(AER), bptest(md1), which it failed (p=0.01). The only way I know how to deal with unequal variances is using a robust anova, library(AER), Anova(md1, vcov.=vcovHC(md1)). However, due to the inclusion of the spray.dmg variable into the model, the big A robust ANOVA does not work (maybe because the spray variable is some sort of covariate) Thus the extent of my knowledge in this matter has been reached. Can anyone please offer some advice?

Comment: Does this model, md1 <- glm(shoot ~ cultivar * as.factor(P) * Waterlogging * herb.dmg.11.DEC+rep,data=iso,family = Gamma) allow for unequal variance? Can you please kindly give an R script example on how to use car::Anova and emmeans::emmeans to examine the output?

Comment: I think `car::Anova(model, white.adjust=TRUE)` is failing because some of the terms in your model are duplicates of other terms; note the terms with 0 degrees of freedom in `Anova(model)`; I didn't really check, tho.